# Google Webpage Screenshot Preview API

Tags: screenshot, google-api, webpage-screenshot

Is there a way to access the google search api, with its repository of website screenshots?

Comment: I'm afraid not, but you can use one of the API's listed on the site below to capture screenshots yourself.

http://freescreenshotapi.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.

Even so for the website screenshots Google is seems to use other services. Check on [URL2PNG](https://www.url2png.com/) website footer, they are claimed to be trusted by teams of Google, also Twitter, GitHub, etc.